# Nginx rewrites for wildcard domains

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, subdomain, wildcard

I have wildcard domains set up, and I am trying to make it so that rewrite rules apply to one subdomain and not another subdomain, and also not to the main domain.

```
server{
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name    _;
    root           /usr/share/nginx/html/$http_host;
    index          index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    include /usr/share/nginx/conf/mission13.io.conf;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

As you can see I am including `mission13.io.conf` in there is where my rewrites will be, I have tried a few different things and nothing has worked, such as this:

```
rewrite ^http://sub.mission13.io/(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1&action=$2&ajax=0;
```

I have also tried this:

```
location sub.missison13.io/ {
    rewrite ^(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1&action=$2&ajax=0;
}
```

Neither of those two methods work. What could I do to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to rewrite all requests to http://sub.mission13.io ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to create a new `server` block and put your rewrites in it:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name sub.mission13.io;

    # everything else #

    include /usr/share/nginx/conf/mission13.io.conf;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name    _;
    root           /usr/share/nginx/html/$http_host;
    index          index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Of couse you can do it without a second `server` block using a `if` block, but that would be bad, not elegant and inefficent.

```
if ($http_host = sub.mission13.io) {
    rewrite ^(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1&action=$2&ajax=0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I use the `if` method, I know it isn't efficient, but I don't need efficiency because the website won't receive many requests, as it is for our customers and not for the public.